# More detail in -WhatIf console returns?

Tags: powershell, scripting

Say I have something like this:

```
Function New-bhReportToGroup {

    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)] 
    $Log1 = "New group for " + $manager + " has been created."
    $Log2 = "Group for " + $manager + " already exists."
    $script:ReportsTo = $ReportsTo -replace ("Report to ", "")
    if ($manager -notin $ReportsTo) { 
        new-adgroup -name "Report to $manager" -groupscope global -path $ou
        $LogLine = $Log1
        Log-Write -LogPath $sLogFile -LineValue $LogLine 
    }
    else {
        $LogLine = $Log2
        Log-Write -LogPath $sLogFile -LineValue $LogLine 
    }
}
```

If I -WhatIf this I get console returns like:

> What if: Performing the operation "Add Content" on target "Path:
> C:\Users\Documents\powershell\Logs\Set-LitmosGroups_2021-03-03_10-11-58.log".

Is this the best it can get?  Detail-wise I mean.. Is there any way to get a bit more granularity from -WhatIf?

Comment: You get what each cmdlet deems to be sufficient detail. If you want more (or on a higher level), implement more yourself by using [`$PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-shouldprocess#pscmdletshouldprocess) and/or `$WhatIfPreference`. However, even then you would typically not expect more than "Performing the operation 'New-bhReportToGroup' on target '<manager>'".

Comment: If you want to optionally give more detail, the -Verbose flag with Write-Verbose is another option.

Comment: I was afraid of this answer.. meaning that -WhatIf returns what it wants and if you don't like it, make your own.. lol.